# move focus with keys other than tab key

Tags: qt, focus, qwidget

Suppose i have a `Qwidget` with three child widgets in it. How can i move focus between child widgets by pressing keys other than tab key? is there any built-in mechanism in `Qt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setFocus()` method of widgets. Note that you can only set a focus for a widget that accepts focus. For example, buttons, text edits accepts focus by default. Frames, labels do not. You can make widgets accepting focus using `setFocusPolicy()` but usually that is not required.

If your want to attach this action to another key or combination, you can use `QShortcut`. Also you can add an event filter to target widgets and detect keyboard events.

Comment: Do you mean that he should use setFocus only after listening to other keys?  i.e. using it together with [Qt's eventFilter](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter).  I think he's asking about key inputs in addition to focus